# How do I add options to slash commands in discord.py v2?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I wanted to make an option in a slash command, but got

```
    async def embed_create(ctx:discord.Interaction, channels:discord.app_commands.choices[int]):
TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable
```

this is what i tried:

```
@createGroup.command(name='channel', description='Create a channel with emoji.')
@app_commands.rename(channels="Channels to choose from")
@app_commands.describe(channels=[
    discord.app_commands.Choice(name="General", value=1),
    discord.app_commands.Choice(name="Media", value=2)
])
async def embed_create(ctx:discord.Interaction, channels:discord.app_commands.choices[int]):
    if channels.name == "General":
        ctx.response.send_message("you chose general")
    elif channels.name == "Media":
        ctx.response.send_message("you chose media")
```

Comment: It is okay if you sometimes don‘t know something but make sure to check the documentation sometimes too ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can see an [example](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=choices#discord.app_commands.choices) in the ****documentation****

```py
@app_commands.command()
@app_commands.describe(fruits='fruits to choose from')
@app_commands.choices(fruits=[
    Choice(name='apple', value=1),
    Choice(name='banana', value=2),
    Choice(name='cherry', value=3),
])
async def fruit(interaction: discord.Interaction, fruits: Choice[int]): #here in this line the error lies, replace your app_commands etc etc with (see below)
    await interaction.response.send_message(f'Your favourite fruit is {fruits.name}.')

#If that does not work, try 

@app_commands.command()
@app_commands.describe(fruits='fruits to choose from')
async def fruit(interaction: discord.Interaction, fruits: Literal['apple', 'banana', 'cherry']):
    await interaction.response.send_message(f'Your favourite fruit is {fruits}.')
```

so it‘d just be channels: Choice[int]